# Which is the most efficient way to persist a string for retrieving spans of text?

Tags: text, data-structures, nosql, bigdata, storage-engines

I need a way to store just one large text on disk without loading it entirely in memory.

My queries are in the form of spans of text, such as: give me all the text between position x and position x + n, nothing more, nothing less. I don't have frequent changes to text.

Probably I need something like a "persistent" B-Tree.

It would also need some DBMS features like:

- a client / server architecture
- a cache system

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a nice task for mmap() (if you happen to live in unixland)

Answer (score 0):

> It would also need some DBMS features like: ...

So, why don't you use a DBMS?
Or even a NoSQL solution with query capabilities, like OrientDB?

I think you could do something like this.

1. Split your text in chunks (chapters? paragraphs? fixed size?)
2. Save your text in a table with (at least) three fields:
   TEXT (the chunk of text)
   BEGIN (the offset of this chunk from the beginning of full text)
   END (the end offset of this chunk from the beginning of full text)

Now you can write your query to extract text between position x and position x+n.

```
SELECT TEXT, BEGIN END  
  FROM TEXT_TABLE  
 WHERE END >= x  
   AND BEGIN <= (x+n)  
ORDER BY BEGIN
```

Finaly you have only to extract your text doing something like:
- From first row: substring(TEXT, (x-BEGIN))
- From "inner" rows: all TEXT
- From last row: substring(TEXT, 0, (x+n-BEGIN))

Obviously, you should also take care of "edge cases" (result with only one or two rows, requested span out of range, ...).
But I think that this approach should solve your problem without too much effort.

Hope it helps.
Bye,
*Raf*

Comment: That's a good idea, in the case of changing text, I should update the whole table but that's not a big problem in my scenario. It was looking a bit strange to me the use of a such complex piece of software to just handle this simple query.

Comment: Yes, the query is simple, but you said you would also like query capabilities, client/server architecture, cache...